# Why LINQ operator can't add statement block?

Tags: c#, linq

I found C# LINQ operator example are all `n => "statement"`. When I try to follow a block( more than one statement), it failed like:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
   .Select(n => { var m = n + 1; m > 10 ? "true" : "false"; });   //failed
```

Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not LINQ that's preventing you it's C#. A statement without a side-effect is an illegal syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You need a `return`

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(n => 
          {  
              var m = n + 1; 
              return m > 10 ? "true" : "false"; 
          });
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(n =>  n + 1 > 10 ? "true" : "false");
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(n => (n + 1 > 10).ToString());
```

---

To be more specific, this isn't *Linq* as such. The signature is

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

and the parameter is

```
Func<TSource, TResult> selector
```

Its basically expects a method with a return type (function), no return, no cigar